# Kim et al.'s (2006) waste collection VRP-IF

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, test-instances

I cannot find a link for the instances of Kim et al.'s (2006) waste collection VRP-IF. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054805001322. The link mentioned in the paper and the citing papers is broken!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found the correct link: http://logistics.postech.ac.kr/benchmark.html